# Regular Expression to Match String Exactly?

Tags: java, regex

I'll preface this question by mentioning that while I'm far from a regular expressions guru, they are not completely foreign to me. Building a regular expression to search for a pattern inside a particular string generally isn't a problem for me, but I have a (maybe?) unique situation.

I have a set of values, say:

> 028938
>   DEF567987
>   390987.456
>   GHI345928.039

I want to match a certain set of strings, such as:

- Strings composed of exactly 6 digits
- Strings composed of exactly 6 digits, a decimal, followed by exactly 3 more digits

In the above examples, the first and third values should be matched.

I'm using the regular expressions:

```
[0-9]{6}
[0-9]{6}.[0-9]{3}
```

Unfortunately, since all the above examples *contain* the specified pattern, all values are matched. This is not my intention.

So my question, in a nutshell, is how to write a regular expression that matches a string exactly and completely, with no additional characters to the right or left of the matched pattern? Is there a term for this type of matching? (Google was no help.) TIA

Comment: How are you using these regexes?  You don't need start or end anchors if you're using `Matcher.matches()` or `String.matches()`, but you will if you're using `Matcher.find()`.  Also you need to escape the dot (`"[0-9]{6}\\.[0-9]{3}"`).

Comment: pattern "anchors" are what `^` and `$` are called.

Comment: you are not escaping the dot so it is going to match a lot of stuff you might not want, see my answer for a really useful web based RegEx tool, and links to tests for my answers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that the dot was treated as a special character.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

use `^` and `$` to match the start and end of your string

```
^[0-9]{6}$
^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$
```

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Also, as noted by Mikael Svenson, you can use the word boundary `\b` if you are searching for this pattern in a larger chunk of text.

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

You could also write both those regexes in one shot

```
^\d{6}(\.\d{3})?$
```

Comment: your answer is wrong, you need to escape the dot, it should also use \d instead of [0-9]

Comment: @msw, true, I did just copy/paste craig's *working* regex, I'll fix it now

Comment: Thanks a lot Chad, both for a working regex and for explaining *why* it works.

Comment: @fuzzy: Using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` is not necessarily an error. Especially not in Java, where they mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `^` to require the matching at the start of a line and `$` to require the end of a line

```
^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$
```

[0-9] can also be written as \d

```
^\d{6}\.\d{3}$
```

You can also use `\b` for word boundaries if you want to match your pattern in a line with eg. spaces in them

```
\btest\b
```

will match the word `test` in this line

```
this is a test for matching
```

Comment: this won't do what he wants you need to escape the dot

Comment: @fuzzy: true.. and you could edit the question to make it proper :) And it will work as . for wildcard will also match a dot ;) But it will also match wrong answers of-course if they are present.

Comment: the question is wrong and needs to stay wrong, that is part of the question, he has the wrong syntax, fixing his question won't let people that have the same type of problem understand the __correct__ answers

Comment: @fuzzy: The question is about matching the start and end of a pattern/line, not how the . wildcard works.

Comment: no the question is about how to EXACTLY match an input with a regular expression, the un-escaped do prevents that EXACT match, the begin and end markers are a red herring to correct answer. his example was not doing what he thought it was doing and needs to be corrected for a totally useful correct solution.

Comment: Some people just love to be annoying don't they?

Answer (score 4):

```
^\d{6}$
^\d{6}\.\d{3}$
```

are the correct patterns you can test them [6 digits only](http://rubular.com/r/wHFovhPPYV) and [6 digits dot 3 digits](http://rubular.com/r/d1uTboBry8).

```
^\d{6}((\.\d{3}$)|$)
```

will match either [6 digits or 6 digits dot 3 digits](http://rubular.com/r/UCBfjIBlSm)

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is your friend!

Answer (score 2):

Match this regex:

```
"^\d{6}((\.\d{3}$)|$)"
```

Comment: or I think, just `^\d{6}(\.\d{3})?$`

Comment: @Chad No. This would not match the first condition - "Strings composed of exactly 6 digits"

Answer (score 2):

i think you want something like this:

```
"^\d{6}(\.\d{3})?$"
```

you need to escape the "dot" as it is "any" character in regexp.