# Get substring matching pattern with fixed length

Tags: java, regex

I try to get substring with fixed length and pattern.

```
Pattern:
***********<<*******<*******<<<<<<<*

Charcates/numbers:
0123456789A<<BCDEFGH<IJKLMNO<<<<<<<P


* = A-Z0-9
```

I have:

```
String input = "ZIO<UP<GKJHGKJHGJ0123456789A<<BCDEFGH<IJKLMNO<<<<<<<PJHGKJHGKJ";
```

I want to get:

```
String output = "0123456789A<<BCDEFGH<IJKLMNO<<<<<<<P";
```

What is the best way to extract this substring?
Some regex suggestions?

Comment: Any attempts at the problem so far?

Comment: WHen I read "fixed length" I think of `substring`. Don't use regexes for that.

Comment: You're not clear. What should be matched in `String string = "A00000000000<<0000000<0000000<<<<<<<0B";` ?

Comment: @sln there should be matched "00000000000<<0000000<0000000<<<<<<<0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get: `0123456789A<<BCDEFGH<IJKLMNO<<<<<<<P` .. How can I extract this substring?

**Update**: You can use the following.

```
String s  = "GKJHGKJHGJ0123456789A<<BCDEFGH<IJKLMNO<<<<<<<PJHGKJHGKJ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9]{11}<<[A-Z0-9]{7}<[A-Z0-9]{7}<{7}[A-Z0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/sM8bN4)

You could probably simplify this a bit:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9]{11}<<[^<]*<[^<]*<{7}[A-Z0-9]");
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/kI4rW8)

Comment: I have problems matching from this string "56789A<<GKJHGKJHGJ0123456789A<<BCDEFGH<IJKLMNO<<<<<<<PJHGKJHGKJ". I need 36 characters, but get 48

Comment: I need to match [A-Z0-9](11x)<<[A-Z0-9](7x)<[A-Z0-9](7x)<<<<<<<[A-Z0-9](1x)

Comment: Solution from @Jerry works well, can you update your java code with his pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
"^[A-Z0-9]+<<[A-Z0-9]+<[A-Z0-9]+<{7}[A-Z0-9]$"
```

- `^ and $` => matching line start/end
- `<{7}` => for matching `<` 7 times
- `[A-Z0-9]+` => for matching 1 or more upper case letter or digits

Comment: Why a `P` literal at the end, and why `[A-Z0-9]+` when he is showing at template where `*`s have quantity and value?

Comment: From OP: `* = A-Z0-9` and about `P` OP had `<<<<<<<P` in description and sample which I interpreted as requirement to match literal `P` but I may have misinterpreted that P

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
[A-Z0-9]{11}<<[A-Z0-9]{7}<[A-Z0-9]{7}<{7}[A-Z0-9]
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kE4uE3)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit fuzzy.

If `*` can be any A-Z0-9 character, then the code would simply be:

```
final String result = string.subString(5, 10); // e.g.
```

Although I may get a downvote for this, I'm under the impression that the `<` characters are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use the `^` and `$` to get your exact word, or even the simple `\bword\b` pattern.

A useful answer: [Regular Expression to Match String Exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479324/regular-expression-to-match-string-exactly).

*Update: please disregard this; i misread, thought you were trying to get an exact word. The answer provided by anubhava should get you going.*

Answer (score 0):

This could be unfactored or partially factored. You should factor based on
whats easier to read/maintain.

```
 # "[0-9A-Z]{11}<(?:<[0-9A-Z]{7}){2}<<<<<<<[0-9A-Z]"

 [0-9A-Z]{11} 
 <
 (?:
      < [0-9A-Z]{7} 
 ){2}
 <<<<<<<
 [0-9A-Z]
```