# Pattern to exclude reserved words in Java / Kotlin

Tags: java, regex, validation, kotlin

I have a field with validation in my class. I need to exclude reserved words in the name:

```
data class SomeData (
@field:Size(min = 1, max = 128)
@field:Pattern(regexp = "(?!(id|name|description))[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*")
val name: String,

val description: String
)
```

when I'm trying to save entity with name 'id' I get an error. All works as I expect. But when I use the name 'idp' I get an error again. But It is a normal name. All should work without error. When the reserved word is not at the beginning all works fine (for example 'pid', 'hidkk'). I need to get errors only when I'm using exactly reserved words. How to fix it?

UPDATED: Such question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479324/regular-expression-to-match-string-exactly) but from that question regular expression, I don't understand how it related to my situation, and also the answer doesn't suitable for my case and doesn't work. @Wiktor Stribiżew gave the correct answer.

Comment: Use `"(?!(id|name|description)$)[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.